# How to save a jpg image to my own directory in sd card

Tags: android

I have updated the following code to following line changes but did not work:

//set the `Image` location

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Skynet/images/t1.jpg" );

Uri uriTarget = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

I want to save the `jpeg` to the above directory, but do not know since it is using the media store.  Any tip to do this.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AndroCamera extends Activity {
   private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
   private Button startBtn;
   private Uri imageUri;
   private ImageView imageView;

/** Called when the activity is first created.
 *  sets the content and gets the references to
 *  the basic widgets on the screen like
 *  {@code Button} or {@link ImageView}
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startCamera();
        }
    });
}

public void startCamera() {
    Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
    String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
            "Image capture by camera");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you added the proper permissions in your manifest? You need permission to write to the external storage. If you are unsure, post your manifest.xml file here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thats because the `Uri` you are using is from the media manager, perhaps if you use the defined `Uri` you want it to be saved to, it should work.
Here is a hint:

```
mImageUri= Uri.fromFile( new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "pic_" + String.valueOf( System.currentTimeMillis() ) + ".jpg" ) );
```

in this it was saved to the root, but since you are creating the file, then you can place it wherever you want to. Just make sure the directory exist otherwise create it.
And as @Simon said, make sure you have the permission to write on external storage.

**Update 1:**
currently you have something like:

```
imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

so the insert is only inserting the image to the `MediaStore` table... but if thats what you actually need, then you need to override the `Data` column in `MediaStore`.
adding on your `contentValues` something like this:

```
values.put( MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, fullPath );
```

if you do not need to use the `MediaStore` table then there is no need to do the insert and therefore the `ContentValues` aren't needed.

Comment: what about mediastore, does this need to be removed?

Comment: I just edited my answer so you can understand it a bit better.

Comment: String fullPath = "/GV-Skynet/images/t1.jpg";        
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/GV-Skynet/images/t1.jpg" );
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        values.put( MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, fullPath );
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: I just wrote in the update :) fullpath is the path to your file to be saved to including the name of your file

Comment: remember that to create your path you should have something like:
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/myfolder/myfile.jpg" for example.

Comment: you actually have the path already... u have File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Skynet/images/t1.jpg" ); so all you have to do is call file.getpath()